# Как разрешить wsl2 доступ к localhost

Tags: windows, ip, wsl

Имеется **ubuntu** на **wsl2**, с неё не могу подключиться ни к какому порту на основной системе (windows 10).
Антивирус отключал, правило в фаерволе настроил, однако ответ всё один: `Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. Пробовал также подключаться через ip адрес компьютера в локалке, однако там `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/networking

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/networking

**Доступ к сетевым приложениям Windows из Linux (IP-адрес основной системы)**
Если вы хотите получить доступ к сетевому приложению, работающему в Windows (например, к приложению, работающему на NodeJS или SQL Server) из дистрибутива Linux (напр., Ubuntu), необходимо использовать IP-адрес основной системы. Хотя это происходит и нечасто, для этого можно выполнить следующие действия.

1. Получите IP-адрес основной системы, выполнив следующую команду из дистрибутива Linux: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
2. Скопируйте IP-адрес в строке, начинающейся с **nameserver**.
3. Подключитесь к любому серверу Windows, используя скопированный IP-адрес.